# How do I reduce size/resolution of an image before uploading to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a image to firebase storage but large images are making my app lag/slow so I want to scale down images or are there any other alternatives

Comment: research on image compression. You can compress bitmaps to JPEG or PNG etc. By the way, make sure you upload in a separate thread (use Async task) because you do not want to block your UI thread while uploading

Comment: @SURAJ BISHT, did my answer help? I think that compressing the bitmap to a JPEG should solve the issue of making the image smaller so that the app does not lag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that you can use to do it. You need to pass in the `bitmap` of your image into the function:

```
private void doUpload(Bitmap bitmap) {
    //Change this to your picture name.
    String s = "MyPicture.jpg";
    StorageReference storageReference2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(s);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    //Compress the original bitmap down into a JPEG.
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data2 = baos.toByteArray();

    //Get an array of the bytes and upload it to Firebase Storage.
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference2.putBytes(data2);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            makeToast("Exception " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            makeToast("Picture uploaded.");
        }
    });
}
```

This should upload the picture to Firebase Storage. It compresses the image to a JPEG. You can change the name of the picture by changing the value of the String `s` above. Hope this helps.